# How to style tooltip of bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to style my `bootstrap 4 tool-tip` . I want to change its background color,height,width and border.
I am not finding any way to style it according to me.

Here is my HTML

`<i class="fa fa-question-circle "href="#" data-toggle="tool-tip" title="Cover for any accidental loss or damage to the vehicle caused by natural calamities such as floods, storms, earthquakes, etc." aria-hidden="true"> </i>`

Tool-tip working fine but I am not able to style it.

Comment: first: instead of  `data-toggle="tool-tip"` set `data-toggle="tooltip"`

Comment: Please add your proper code with css html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out the below example with different styles:

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Default">Default</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-type="primary" title="Primary">Primary</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-type="info" title="Info">Info</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-type="success" title="Success">Success</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-type="warning" title="Warning">Warning</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-type="danger" title="Danger">Danger</button>
```

CSS:

```
.tooltip.primary .tooltip-inner          { background-color:    #337ab7; }
.tooltip.primary.top > .tooltip-arrow    { border-top-color:    #337ab7; }
.tooltip.primary.right > .tooltip-arrow  { border-right-color:  #337ab7; }
.tooltip.primary.bottom > .tooltip-arrow { border-bottom-color: #337ab7; }
.tooltip.primary.left > .tooltip-arrow   { border-left-color:   #337ab7; }

.tooltip.info .tooltip-inner          { background-color:    #31b0d5; }
.tooltip.info.top > .tooltip-arrow    { border-top-color:    #31b0d5; }
.tooltip.info.right > .tooltip-arrow  { border-right-color:  #31b0d5; }
.tooltip.info.bottom > .tooltip-arrow { border-bottom-color: #31b0d5; }
.tooltip.info.left > .tooltip-arrow   { border-left-color:   #31b0d5; }

.tooltip.success .tooltip-inner          { background-color:    #449d44; }
.tooltip.success.top > .tooltip-arrow    { border-top-color:    #449d44; }
.tooltip.success.right > .tooltip-arrow  { border-right-color:  #449d44; }
.tooltip.success.bottom > .tooltip-arrow { border-bottom-color: #449d44; }
.tooltip.success.left > .tooltip-arrow   { border-left-color:   #449d44; }

.tooltip.warning .tooltip-inner          { background-color:    #ec971f; }
.tooltip.warning.top > .tooltip-arrow    { border-top-color:    #ec971f; }
.tooltip.warning.right > .tooltip-arrow  { border-right-color:  #ec971f; }
.tooltip.warning.bottom > .tooltip-arrow { border-bottom-color: #ec971f; }
.tooltip.warning.left > .tooltip-arrow   { border-left-color:   #ec971f; }

.tooltip.danger .tooltip-inner          { background-color:    #d9534f; }
.tooltip.danger.top > .tooltip-arrow    { border-top-color:    #d9534f; }
.tooltip.danger.right > .tooltip-arrow  { border-right-color:  #d9534f; }
.tooltip.danger.bottom > .tooltip-arrow { border-bottom-color: #d9534f; }
.tooltip.danger.left > .tooltip-arrow   { border-left-color:   #d9534f; }
```

Here is complete working code:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pVGKpW

Comment: Just a short note - don't nest the style rules within an inner element, since the tooltips are appended dynamically.

Comment: In case you're using **react-bootstrap**, here's the equivalent code example, in my example, dark text on a white background: 

.tooltip .tooltip-inner {
  color: #181818;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.tooltip.bs-tooltip-top > .arrow::before {
  border-top-color: #fff;
}